# i want div content disappears after i click on textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #myloc,#mypass{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

function validateform(){  
var username=document.login.username.value;  
var password=document.login.password.value;    
if (username==null || username==""){  
  var data="username should not be blank.";
  document.getElementById("myloc").innerHTML=data;
  return false;  
}else if(password.length<6){  
  var p="Password must be at least 6 characters long.";
  document.getElementById("mypass").innerHTML=p;
  return false;  
  }  
}  
</script>
    <body>
        <form action="/loginusingservlet/LoginSES" onsubmit="return validateform()" method="post" name="login">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td>username</td><td> <input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><div id="myloc"></div></td>            
                </tr><tr><td>password</td><td> <input type="text" name="password"></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><div id="mypass"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this program works great...when i click submit buttons it displays messages like "username should not be blank " or "password atleast 6".after getting message..if i click on a textbox i want the message disappear untill i click "submit" button.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?  I don't see any indication that you've event attempted to clear the message when an input is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. New function in script (it checks argument and removes text from specific element:

```
function removeWarning(type)
{
    (type == 1) ? document.getElementById('myloc').innerHTML = "" : document.getElementById('mypass').innerHTML = "";
}
```

And add `onClick` event in inputs.

```
<input type="text" name="username" onClick="removeWarning(1)">

<input type="text" name="password" onClick="removeWarning(2)">
```

To me it is working but it was a quick solution, it is possible to improve a little.

Comment: @simonasir Don't forget to check as solved so others could see too!

Comment: Edvin i have another problem, when i using tab key,the message exists..

Comment: @simonasir You can additionally add `onKeyDown` event just like with `onClick`.

Comment: @simonasir But you didn't mark that accepted (since it's working). Future visitors will not be sure.